# How to get the result from a RootSum?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

While working on an integral, I got this scary-looking expression. I tried to use
`// Normal // ToRadicals // FullSimplify` to get the answer, but it is taking lot of time. I don't know how to do it in a simple way.Please help me in this regard, thanks in advance.

```
 2 \[Pi] - 
 RootSum[1 + 2 #1^2 + 6 n #1^2 - 6 n^2 #1^2 + 2 n^3 #1^2 - 23 #1^4 + 
    50 n #1^4 - 25 n^2 #1^4 - 12 n^3 #1^4 + 15 n^4 #1^4 - 6 n^5 #1^4 +
     n^6 #1^4 + 36 #1^6 - 168 n #1^6 + 316 n^2 #1^6 - 304 n^3 #1^6 + 
    156 n^4 #1^6 - 40 n^5 #1^6 + 4 n^6 #1^6 &, Log[-#1]/#1 &]
```

Comment: That _is_ the answer. It won't simplify further. If you want a numerical value you need to provide a value for `n`. If you choose `n=1` you get $4\pi$ :  `FullSimplify[thething /. n -> 1]`

Comment: I have the numerical values, I need a closed-form or a nice output from that expression. Thanks.

Comment: There are some `n` that work e.g `FullSimplify[ToRadicals[thething/.n->4]]` gives you $2 \left(4+\sqrt{7}\right) \pi$, `n=3` gives you $8\pi$, and `n=1` gives you $4\pi$, but most others e.g `n=6`  do not simplify to anything nice.

Comment: What do you need the closed form for? What integral did this come from?

Comment: Integrate[Log[16*(n - 1)^4*x^6 + (4*(n - 3)*(n - 1)^2*x^4 + 1 + 
              ((n - 1)^3 + 4)*x^2)^2]/x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}] This is the integral. 'n' is a positive integer.

Answer (score 5):

`RootSum[]` is necessary for reasons similar to why `Root[]` is needed: namely, as a way to represent sums of a function over the roots of a polynomial. In brief, if you have the expression

```
r == RootSum[C[0] + C[1] # + ... + C[n] #^n &, f[#] &]
```

this is equivalent to

$$r=\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k),\qquad c_n x_k^n+\cdots+c_1 x_k+c_0=0,\; k=1,\dots,n$$

---

In the case of the expression you have, note that the generating polynomial (i.e. the first argument of `RootSum[]`) has the following structure:

```
Collect[1 + 2 #1^2 + 6 n #1^2 - 6 n^2 #1^2 + 2 n^3 #1^2 - 23 #1^4 + 50 n #1^4 -
        25 n^2 #1^4 - 12 n^3 #1^4 + 15 n^4 #1^4 - 6 n^5 #1^4 + n^6 #1^4 + 36 #1^6 -
        168 n #1^6 + 316 n^2 #1^6 - 304 n^3 #1^6 + 156 n^4 #1^6 - 40 n^5 #1^6 +
        4 n^6 #1^6 &[x], x]
   1 + (2 + 6 n - 6 n^2 + 2 n^3) x^2 +
   (-23 + 50 n - 25 n^2 - 12 n^3 + 15 n^4 - 6 n^5 + n^6) x^4 +
   (36 - 168 n + 316 n^2 - 304 n^3 + 156 n^4 - 40 n^5 + 4 n^6) x^6
```

and you should immediately observe that all the powers involved are *even*. This means that if we let $u=x^2$, we get a polynomial that is cubic in $u$, which lends itself to using things like Cardano's formula to express the roots.

*I won't go that far.* (The sufficiently masoch- ...er, motivated reader is free to go further than me.) Instead, the obervation of even powers is why you get the following result after applying `Normal[]`:

[image: Normal result]

and you should now notice that you obtain a result of the form $\sum_k\frac{\log(-x_k)}{x_k}$, where the $x_k$ come in $\pm\sqrt{\cdot}$ pairs, corresponding to the roots of the cubic polynomial I mentioned earlier. You could try using `ToRadicals[]` to get the Cardano-like radical form, but it won't be pretty.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, sir, I will try in this way.